# Coloring network edges by weight using GraphPlot

Tags: graphs-and-networks, color

Following up on a previous question about how to color the nodes (vertices) of a network (graph) according to a color scaling of a property of those nodes, I'm now asking basically the same thing about edges:

> How can I color the edges of a graph (using a gradient color scheme) according to the weight (or other property) of the edges using `GraphPlot`?

It's easy if one just wants some conditional coloring (using "`If[]`"), but I (and I guess many people) want color scaling.  Although there are some examples here that don't use `GraphPlot`, they won't work for me.

I did find one post that included something like an answer, but it was so complicated that I couldn't port it over to my case.  So I'm trying to use the `EdgeRenderingFunction` and I can't get it to work.

To make this concrete, Here is a graph and a plot of a graph with edge weights between `-1` and `1`:

```
SomeGraph = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[{{∞, 1, .8, ∞, -1}, {1, ∞, .6, -1, ∞},
            {1, .6, ∞, ∞, -.6}, {∞, -0.5, ∞, ∞, 1}, {-1, ∞, -1, 1, ∞}},
            DirectedEdges -> False];
TheCoordinates = {{0, 1},{0, 2}, {0, 3}, {2, 1.5}, {2,2.5}};
PlotOfSomeGraph=GraphPlot[SomeGraph,
                          VertexCoordinateRules-> TheCoordinates, 
                          VertexRenderingFunction -> 
                    (Inset[Graphics[{Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, .01]}, ImageSize -> 17], #] &)]
```

And now I'd like to add an `EdgeRenderingFunction` to that `GraphPlot` so that they are colored on a rescaled reversed temperature map.  I know that some adaptation of

```
EdgeRenderingFunction -> 
  ({Opacity[0.5],ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}][Rescale[...]], Line[#1]} &)
```

And to fill in the gap I can access some edge information using #1 for the endpoint coordinates, #2 for the start and ending vertices, and #3 for the edge label.

I might be able to kludge something using `EdgeLabels`, but because coloring edges by weight (or other property) is a basic feature of all other network tools I expect (or at least I expected) a simple way to do this in Mathematica (version 10.1).

Comment: any reason to use GraphPlot instead Graph?

Comment: Yes, but mostly because I had used it before.  However, if you would like to provide an answer using Graph showing how it is just as good or better, then I would certainly be interested in seeing that and it would also benefit the community.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
wam = WeightedAdjacencyMatrix@SomeGraph;
erf = ({ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}][Rescale[wam[[Sequence @@ #2]],
                                                              {Min@wam, Max@wam}]],
        Line[#1]} &);
PlotOfSomeGraph = GraphPlot[
                            SomeGraph,
                            VertexCoordinateRules -> TheCoordinates,
                            EdgeRenderingFunction -> (erf)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

**Edit**

Packing it as a function

```
erf[wam_] := {ColorData["MintColors"][Rescale[wam[[Sequence@@#2]], {Min@wam, Max@wam}]], 
                Line[#1]}&;
gp[wam_] := GraphPlot[WeightedAdjacencyGraph[wam, DirectedEdges -> False], 
                      Method -> "CircularEmbedding",
                      EdgeRenderingFunction -> (erf[wam])]

gp[SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> i + j, {15, 15}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That works, but I don't understand it 100%.  What work is being done by "Sequence @@ #2" (= "Apply[Sequence,#2]" in which #2 is the pair of vertices for the edge)?  I know the output of that part is "Sequence[v1,v2]", but I don't understand how that is pulling the correct item from the adjacency matrix (while using the list {v1,v2} fails to work).  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `wam[[Sequence @@ #2]]` is retrieving the weight of the edge between `v1` and `v2`

Comment: Right, "but I don't understand how that is pulling the correct item from the adjacency matrix (while using the list {v1,v2} fails to work). Could you please elaborate? "  Specifically, why is a "sequence" the right thing for the job?  It's not clear from the definitions and, as usual, the official documentation is totally worthless.

Comment: @AaronBramson It isn't a problem with this particular piece of documentation, but a general Mathematica thing. Try this `list = {{a,b},{ c, d}, {e,f}}; ind = {1,2}; Print@list[[ind]]; Print@list[[Sequence@@ind]];`

Comment: I see, so `list[[Sequence@@ind]]` equivalent to `list[[ind[[1]]]][[ind[[2]]]]` because there are only two elements of ind, but is more general. Your way of writing it is less intuitive (less noob-friendly) but now that I understand how it translates into basic commands it's clearly better to write it your way.

Comment: I also agree that "It isn't a problem with this particular piece of documentation, but a general Mathematica thing."  Yes, the Mathematica documentation is generally quite horrible, it's not any particular piece.

Comment: @AaronBramson Mathematica docs are an acquired taste, yes. After a few years you may come to terms with them :). I usually try to write the best code I can come up to, disregarding considerations about the knowledge level of the question. The reason being that Mathematica front  end is a nice interactive platform that allows you to test each function, one at a time, and learn in the process

Comment: @AaronBramson In fact `list[[Sequence@@ind]]` is `list[[ind[[1]], ind[[2]]]]`

Answer (score 4):

With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), colouring based on edge weights:

```
Graph[SomeGraph, EdgeStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[4], VertexCoordinates -> TheCoordinates] // 
  IGEdgeMap[ColorData["Rainbow"], EdgeStyle -> Rescale@*IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice how the per-vertex setting of the [`EdgeStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeStyle.html) (by `IGEdgeMap`) did not revert the global `EdgeStyle` setting for thickness.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set EdgeStyle to do this (using Graph):

```
Graph[SomeGraph, 
 EdgeStyle -> 
  Thread[EdgeList[
     SomeGraph] -> (Directive[Opacity[0.5], 
        ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}][#]] & /@ 
      Rescale[PropertyValue[SomeGraph, EdgeWeight]])], 
 GraphStyle -> "ThickEdge", VertexCoordinates -> TheCoordinates]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks good too.  I typically have a few thousand sparsely connected nodes that are also sized and colored by data...and hundreds of those per analysis.  Any idea if there is a clear performance winner between Graph vs GraphPlot and Graph3D vs GraphPlot3D?

Answer (score 2):

```
SetProperty[SomeGraph, {ImagePadding -> 10 , VertexCoordinates -> TheCoordinates,
  EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> {CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.1], 
   ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", "Reverse"}]@
     Rescale[PropertyValue[SomeGraph, EdgeWeight]][[EdgeIndex[SomeGraph, e]]]}}}]
```

[image]

Use `Thickness[.001 + Abs[Normalize[PropertyValue[SomeGraph, EdgeWeight]][[EdgeIndex[SomeGraph, e]]]]/5]` to get

[image]