# Coloring edges by weight and changing color but keeping shape for CommunityGraphPlot using PlotTheme->"Marketing"

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, color, style, plot-themes

(Apologies, but I cannot share the data that I am using for these graphs.)

I am finding communities in my data set by using CommunityGraphPlot, and the results looks pretty good:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[OGopt, EdgeWeight -> FOGlist, VertexSize -> OGfreq,
CommunityRegionStyle -> {{Red, Opacity[0.15]}, {Yellow, 
Opacity[0.15]}, {Purple, Opacity[0.15]}, {Orange, Opacity[0.15]}},
VertexStyle -> color]
```

[image]

I really like how the nodes look when I use PlotTheme->"Market" and I think I would like to use this theme moving forward:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[OGopt, EdgeWeight -> FOGlist, VertexSize -> OGfreq,
CommunityRegionStyle -> {{Red, Opacity[0.15]}, {Yellow, 
Opacity[0.15]}, {Purple, Opacity[0.15]}, {Orange, Opacity[0.15]}},
PlotTheme -> "Marketing", Background -> White, 
VertexLabelStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

However, I wanted to change the color of the nodes to represent the three groups I'm comparing, as I have done in the first community graph plot, and I have been trying to make the edge weights more noticable, and attempted to implement the solution I saw [over here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88796/52355) but using the ColorData "BlueGreenYellow", but with no luck - EdgeRenderFunction lights up in red, and doesn't appear to be compatible with CommunityGraphPlot.

When I try using my custom color function, that I used on the first community graph plot, I get some weird halo'ing around the nodes, and the shape reverts back to being just circles, which I don't like at all:

[image]

I want to maintain the unique style of the nodes in the "Marketing" theme. I'm not sure how I would begin tackling this color problem while using the "Marketing" theme, so any advice and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those circle around disk shapes are from highlight plot theme.  For individual color with that style, you could define your own vertex shape function and you could use EdgeStyle to style edges:

```
g = ExampleData[{"NetworkGraph", "DolphinSocialNetwork"}];
SeedRandom[123]; weight = RandomReal[{.5, 2}, EdgeCount[g]];
vsize = Thread[
   VertexList[g] -> RandomReal[{.1, .4}, VertexCount[g]]];
vcolor = Thread[
   VertexList[g] -> (Hue /@ RandomReal[{.1, 1}, VertexCount[g]])];
estyle = Thread[
   EdgeList[g] -> (ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"] /@ Rescale[weight])];

CommunityGraphPlot[g, EdgeWeight -> weight, VertexSize -> vsize, 
 VertexStyle -> vcolor, EdgeStyle -> estyle, 
 CommunityBoundaryStyle -> None, 
 CommunityRegionStyle -> ColorData[10, "ColorList"][[;; ;; 2]], 
 VertexShapeFunction -> ({EdgeForm[], Thickness[.002], 
     Circle[#1, 3.5 #3], Disk[#1, 2 #3]} &)]
```

[image]